# Web API Routing Conflicts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

FYI, I have no custom routing, no usage of MapHttpRoute.

My Web API controller is as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/stat")]
public class StatController : ApiController
```

In that controller I has these methods:

```
  [Route("{statType}")]
    public StatState GetCurrentStat(string statType, UserInfo userInfo)

 [Route("getAllAccount")]
    public Dictionary<string, StatState> GetAllAccountCurrentStat(UserInfo userInfo)

   [Route("getScoreHistory")]
        public StatHistory GetStatAccountScoreHistory(string statType, UserInfo userInfo)
```

An HTTP GET call with this url: `/api/stat/getAllAccount` correctly maps to:

```
 [Route("getAllAccount")]
    public Dictionary<string, StatState> GetAllAccountCurrentStat(UserInfo userInfo)
```

An HTTP GET call with this url: `/api/stat/getScoreHistory` **INCORRECTLY** maps to:

```
[Route("{statType}")]
    public StatState GetCurrentStat(string statType, UserInfo userInfo)
```

**How do I get /api/stat/getScoreHistory to map correctly and why does /api/stat/getAllAccount do as I expected it to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the `statType` parameter in the definition of your third endpoint but not in your `/api/stat/getScoreHistory` URL means that the first of your three endpoints is the best match.

You need to remove the extraneous `statType` parameter from your last endpoint:

```
[Route("getScoreHistory")]
public StatHistory GetStatAccountScoreHistory(UserInfo userInfo)
```

Comment: That did it!, I should have noticed!